# Compound expression in if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, gcc

I stumbled upon the ability to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    if ( ({int i = 1024; i == 10;}) ) {
        cout << "In" << endl;
    }
}
```

The important disassembly area seems to be:

```
->  0x10000118f <+15>: movl   $0x400, -0x18(%rbp)       ; imm = 0x400 
    0x100001196 <+22>: cmpl   $0xa, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x10000119a <+26>: sete   %al
    0x10000119d <+29>: andb   $0x1, %al
    0x10000119f <+31>: movb   %al, -0x19(%rbp)
    0x1000011a2 <+34>: testb  $0x1, -0x19(%rbp)
    0x1000011a6 <+38>: je     0x1000011d9               ; <+89> at main.cpp:37
```

From examining this, it does seem like it takes the last statement (the comparison `i == 10`) as the boolean for the `if` statement.

I understand that this case doesn't allow me to use variable `i` within the if statement because of the scope operator, but wanted to know **why the `if` statement decides to use `i == 10` as the boolean statement.**

For alternatives to this, I understand that a function call might be cleaner which returns a boolean that I can use to set to a variable for the `if` statement. However, I see MACROs that expand to this very similar style within glibc source code.

**Is it an old style of programming with MACROs?**

**Is there a benefit to this I am missing?**

Comment: What else would it use? `i=1024` doesn't return anything

Comment: Thats a "compound expression", a GCC compiler extension.

Comment: Your code is not valid C on account of `using namespace std;`, the `if` expression notwithstanding.

Comment: FWIW this is illegal in C++

Comment: When given the series of statements (compound expression) `{ s1 ; s2 ; ... ; sn }` it's the last statement that is used. it has to pick one. It's just the way the language extension works. Is there a benefit to doing this? No, it just makes the code confusing. A feature that a programmer would use just because it's there.

Comment: But even without that, the expression in the `if` statement is not valid C.  gcc and I guess g++ has an extension that works like that, though.

Comment: @NathanOliver: ... and C

Comment: ..and is available as a GNU extension.

Comment: Note C++17 introduces a standardized way to achieve something similar, called [if-initializers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#If_Statements_with_Initializer).

Comment: I like how people tag questions as C/C++ and yet post non-C compliant code.

Comment: Just take a look at the level of confusion that condition introduces.  The compiler [complains](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7318b6c46032b2dd) about it not being a standard C++ code.

Comment: @малинчекуров, edit the tag away, point it out to them, and maybe they'll learn something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A GCC extension to the C++ language allows a parenthesized compound statement (that is, semicolon-delimited statements, inside braces, inside parentheses) to be used as an expression. To evaluate the expression, the statements are executed in order, and the value of the expression in the last statement is used as the value of the expression as a whole.

It's primarily useful for function-like macros which need to declare local variables of their own. Because it's GCC-specific, it's best to avoid it unless absolutely necessary — and in the case of C++, function-like macros themselves are best avoided, in favor of template functions.

So it's a nice thing to know about, but it's not a good thing to use in C++, even on a compiler which supports it.

EDIT: As Jodocus noted, there's a similar feature available in C++17, whereby a for-loop-style initializer can precede the condition in an if-statement (as it does in a for-statement). Personally I think it's an unnecessary complication, as it has roughly the same effect as just putting the initializer and the if-statement in braces, but in the code you posted it would technically be a valid option.